# How To Sum of Top 1 records from different group of Items of same Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum of total of different groups top1 result.

```
Select PCCI.BWPrintQty 
from PrintCusClickRecord PCCI 
where Convert(Date, pcci.ClickMonth) < Convert(Date, '2019-01-01') 
  and PCCI.OrderID != 129012 and ISNULL(PCCI.IsDelete, 0) != 1 
  and PCCI.ItemTrackingNo in ('C397P800803', 'G145P901553', 'G146P300748') 
order by PCCI.ClickMonth desc
```

Here is the data for

```
Click record for C397P800803        
-------------------------------
300,
200,
100

Click record for G145P901553
-------------------------------
400,
250,
150

Click record for G146P300748
-------------------------------
500,
450,
350
```

Output should be sum of all the first record from the same table given above.
means=300+400+500=1200(result)

Comment: Are you storing numbers as comma delimited string? btw, you have a missed comma in the `IN()`

Comment: You say *first record*, could you clarify? Do you mean the *first row* of a group or the *max* of a group ?

Comment: I need decimal format. want to select 300 from 1st group, 400 from 2nd group, 500 from 3rd group then sum it . result  will be 1200. It can be max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to group the `ItemTrackingNo` by their maximum `BWPrintQty` (I presume that is the column for the numbers in your example, apply the filter you mentioned above in your question, and sum up the result.

```
(select sum(first) from 
  (select 
    max(BWPrintQty) as first, 
    ItemTrackingNo
  from PrintCusClickRecord 
  where 
  Convert(Date,pcci.ClickMonth) < Convert(Date,'2019-01-01') 
  and PCCI.OrderID!= 129012 
  and ISNULL(PCCI.IsDelete,0)!=1 
  and PCCI.ItemTrackingNo in('C397P800803', 'G145P901553' ,'G146P300748') 
  group by ItemTrackingNo)
)
```

Comment: @MdShahnawaz . . . I don't understand why this is the accepted answer.  This is assuming that the largest value is the most recent, and there is nothing in the question that specifies this.  Your query orders by time, not magnitude.

Comment: . . My question was directed to the OP.  I understand your answer, and it is correct under some circumstances (such as for the data given).  However, it seems misleading to accept this, unless the question is clarified so this answer is more generally correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Rank`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
SELECT SUM(PrintQty) FROM (
Select PCCI.BWPrintQty AS PrintQty, RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY PCCI.ItemTrackingNo
    ORDER BY PCCI.ClickMonth desc
) as [Rank]
from PrintCusClickRecord PCCI 
where  Convert(Date,pcci.ClickMonth) < Convert(Date,'2019-01-01') 
and PCCI.OrderID!= 129012 and ISNULL(PCCI.IsDelete,0)!=1 
and PCCI.ItemTrackingNo in('C397P800803'
                           'G145P901553'
                           ,'G146P300748'
                           ) 
) S
WHERE S.[Rank] = 1
```

The query produces value for eg:

```
Click record for C397P800803        
-------------------------------
300, 1
200, 2
100, 3

Click record for G145P901553
-------------------------------
400, 1
250, 2
150, 3

Click record for G146P300748
-------------------------------
500, 1
450, 2
350, 3
```

Then it filters to the records with rank equals 1 => `300, 400, 500` and calc the sum of them.

Answer (score 0):

`Row_number` them as needed and take the first ones.

```
select sum(BWPrintQty) 
from (
    select PCCI.BWPrintQty 
       -- order by PCCI.ClickMonth if you need first month
      , row_number() over(partition by PCCI.ItemTrackingNo order by PCCI.BWPrintQty desc) pos 
    from PrintCusClickRecord PCCI 
    where  Convert(Date,pcci.ClickMonth) < Convert(Date,'2019-01-01') 
       and PCCI.OrderID!= 129012 and ISNULL(PCCI.IsDelete,0)!=1 
       and PCCI.ItemTrackingNo in('C397P800803'
                                ,'G145P901553'
                                ,'G146P300748'
                               ) 
   ) t
where pos = 1;
```